# Way to call server side function from onclick event in gridview?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, gridview, dom-events

I don't love having a 'Select' linkbutton visible in my gridview in some cases.  I would prefer to use the onclick Javascript event to trigger the function, but I would prefer not to perform a postback using the ClientID in the querystring to perform that.  The function being called (LoadProjects) simply hides the current panel with this gridview and shows another one after databinding that second gridview.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClientID = Int16.Parse(GridView1.SelectedValue.ToString());
    LoadProjects(ClientID);
}


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location='somepage.aspx?ClientID=" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + "'");
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
     }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
    }
    e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
}
```

Is there a way to call the `LoadProjects()` function from the onclick event without using querystrings?

Comment: This is confusing and/or doesn't seem right...

Comment: Sorry...I may not be explaining this as well as I'd hope.  Rather than use the onlick event to reload the page and call a function on the postback, is there a way to call the function more directly?  I believe I cannot avoid doing a postback but I'm just looking for any options that someone may be able to provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use the JS function `__doPostBack` to perform a manual post back, see [this article](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/320_Doing_or_Raising_Postback_using___doPostBack%28%29_function_from_Javascript_in_AspNet.aspx) for more information and examples.

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try using session to store the value if dont want to use querystring. but rest remains same..

you cant call serverside method without postback and even that happens only on someevent.

Best option to avoid postback is using ajax.

Comment: You're right as well, Praneeth.  I think eventually I will need to use AJAX here to do exactly what I want.  Thanks.